# Equivalences between Australian English and American English

Tags: american-english, australian-english, resources

Where can I find a good source (book or web page) of equivalences between Australian English and American English? I am looking for ordinary words, clothing-related words, food-related words, etc.

Answer (score 3):

*(I'm answering this because no-one else has, not because I have a good answer.)*

Is [the Australian National Dictionary](http://203.166.81.53/and/) any use?

There used to be quite a funny book of Australian English which was published around the sixties or seventies, but I can't seem to find it on the internet.

Comment: I think the funny book you're referring to is *Let Stalk Strine* by ["Afferbeck Lauder"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afferbeck_Lauder) (you know, like in a dictionary or telephone directory), mentioned [here](http://bitsandpieces.us/2010/08/02/speaking-australian/) and seems to be available [here](http://www.textfiles.com/humor/strine.txt). Really hilarious. :-)

Comment: No, it's not that. It was funny, but it was set out as if it was a real dictionary.

Comment: Hmm, it [*is*](http://www.textfiles.com/humor/strine.txt) set out like a dictionary for the most part, but probably some text was lost and mis-formatted. Or of course, as you say, it may have been a different book.

Comment: Seems like the link in this answer has died, alas.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question should really be what are the Equivalences between Australian English and British English?

Because Australian English is derived from British English and has far more in common with it than it does with US English.
In fact, apart from colloquialisms and a few differences in common phrases Australian and British English are very close indeed.

Comment: There's some truth to this, but Australian English draws from both American and British English in a number of ways. While I admit I take the 'lift' to my 'flat,' I also turn at 'intersections' in my 'station wagon,' and I eat both 'biscuits' and 'cookies,' as the mood takes me.